# Как лучше хранить маленькие значения в большой таблице sqlite3?

Tags: python, sqlite3, sqlite, sql

В таблице предполагается хранить больше миллиарда записей с четырьмя полями: два текстовых по два знака, одно поле с маленькими целочисленными значениями (не превышает трёхсот) и одно булевое.

Как это лучше всего сделать? [Это](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/sqlite3.html) как-то не сильно помогает.

Comment: допустим, что символы кириллицы (что бы побольше, то есть 33 штуки). Получается следующее `1000000000/(33 * 33 * 33 * 33 * 300 * 2) = 1.4`

То есть, треть базы - будет дубликатом (как минимум треть). А это странно.


Может расскажите, что это такое там будет храниться? Тогда может и предложения по оптимизации будут.

А страница с руководства по питону и не должна помогать понимать, как хранить такое кол-во данных.

Comment: @KoVadim, 1.4 чего и как вы это подсчитали?

Хранить будем латинские символы, да и то только 4 различных символа.

Comment: я посчитал кол-во возможных различных строк в базе. 1.4 - это значит, что кол-во записей в базе на больше на 40% возможно количества уникальных вариантов. Если букв будет всего 4, то каждое строковое поле будет по 16 вариантов, а всего 16*16*300*2 = 153600 вариантов.

Поэтому, может просто занумеровать данные и хранить только числа?

Comment: Программе важно, насколько часто все эти варианты повторяются и как их количество будет изменяться со временем.

Comment: так храните по другому. Не храните дубликаты. Просто добавьте ещё одно поле - количество.

А вот как их кол-во будет изменяться со временем - тут не понятно - в Вашей базе нет поля времени.

Comment: Целью программы как раз и является выяснение того, как количество этих объектов будет изменяться со временем. У нас есть объекты, с которыми происходит некий сложный процесс, который занимает одну единицу времени. Ну и состояние базы - это результат действия этого процесса после n единиц времени.

Comment: учитывая то, что в Вашей базе нет поля времени, делать анализ по времени будет сложно (если только программа не генерирует известное кол-во записей в единицу времени).

Вернемся к собственно вопросу. Так что же не получается сделать? Выполнить запрос на таких объемах, питон ругается на базу, Вы не знаете, как посчитать кол-во одинаковых записей.

Может просто сохранять в текстовый файл (это будет даже быстрее работать), а потом простым циклом считать статистику.

Comment: Вообще я хотела прикинуть объём памяти, который потребуется такой таблице и сократить каждую строку. Видимо, и правда, преждевременная оптимизация -- великое зло.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы вообще вам рекомендовал при таких жутких объёмах пользовать модуль shelve. Это интерфейс словаря к базе данных sqlite3.